# Open picture currently displayed in Screen Saver?

Tags: photos.app, screensaver

> **TL;DR** In iTunes, you can press `Command-L` (*Controls/Go to Current Song*) to see what is playing. Is there a similar function to *Go To Current Photo* (in iPhoto) when I see a picture in the screen saver?

My photo library has thousands of pictures. I use the built-in screen saver "Classic" to display the photos.

Sometimes the screen saver displays a photo I'd like to do something more with. Perhaps email it to a friend.

How can I jump to the photo in iPhoto so I can do more with it?

I found one similar question here, but it doesn't cover *Go To Current Photo*:
[How do I enable the interactive iPhoto screen saver in OSX Lion?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/18415/how-do-i-enable-the-interactive-iphoto-screen-saver-in-osx-lion)